# After omitting $ from input getting NaN in javascript asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In javascript, I have given like this,( edited adding Pasman response )

```
var y= document.getElementById('<%= DataItemValue4.ClientID%>').firstChild.nodeValue.replace('$', '');
alert(Number(y));
y = y *48;
```

the value I am reading here is integer type amount with $, ex: $200, $10 etc.,
 and after  omitting `$` symbol, i get ex: `200, 10`. Now before i do arithmetic operations on y, alert shows me value as NaN,even if i don't write Number() also i am getting same problem. how to get numerical y and able to perform arithmetic  operation on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the $ sign like this:

```
var y = document.getElementById('<%= DataItemValue4.ClientID%>')
                .firstChild.nodeValue.replace('$','');
```

Comment: Hi , after that y is added with 50 and need to assign y to a label in the page. problem is y should be passed as ex: if y = 1098 need to assign to label as $1,098 .How can it be done?

Answer (score 2):

If the string is always exactly `'$xxx'` (i.e. no spaces etc), then you just take the substring (with e.g. [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)):

```
val = val.substr(1);
```

If there are spaces, you have to use [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) (basically *trimming* the value):

```
val = val.replace(/^[\s$]+|[\s]+$/g, '');
```

Comment: after that y is added with 50 and need to assign y to a label in the page. problem is y should be passed as ex: if y = 1098 need to assign to label as $1,098 .How can it be done?